# Reactjs - cloneWithProps duplicate class names

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an accordion react component, but everytime when it updates, it create duplicates of classNames.

My codes:
AccordionListComponent Component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
var accordions = this.state.accordions.map(function(accordion, i) {
  nextProps.children[i].props.key = accordion.key;

  var newAc = clone(accordion, nextProps.children[i].props);

  return React.addons.update(accordion, {
    $set: newAc
  });
});

this.setState({
  accordions: accordions
});
},
```

Usage:

```
<AccordionListComponent>
        <AccordionComponent className="date" title={dateTitle} index={0}>
          <DateComponent updateDate={this.updateDate} />
        </AccordionComponent>
</AccordionListComponent>
```

Logs

[image: Console logs]

Based on the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/clone-with-props.html) from ReactJs, it was stating that

```
Do a shallow copy of element and merge any props provided by extraProps. 
The className and style props will be merged intelligently.
```

Are they not removing duplicates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there [is no deduping logic](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f1cd867323c420c577f82628ba498637a3d6e5f7/src/utils/joinClasses.js):

```
function joinClasses(className/*, ... */) {
  if (!className) {
    className = '';
  }
  var nextClass;
  var argLength = arguments.length;
  if (argLength > 1) {
    for (var ii = 1; ii < argLength; ii++) {
      nextClass = arguments[ii];
      if (nextClass) {
        className = (className ? className + ' ' : '') + nextClass;
      }
    }
  }
  return className;
}
```

Note that `cloneWithProps` [is deprecated](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html#deprecations) in favor of the new `React.cloneElement`, which does *not* merge classes or styles for you.